# How to fill a vector by a while loop

Tags: r, vector, while-loop

I´m starting to learn R.

I would be glad if someone could help me with filling *myVec* by a while loop.

Here is my (wrong) code:

```
a <- 0
b <- 10
myVec <- c(x)
while(a < b) {
a <- a+1
x <- a
print(a)
}
```

Comment: Do you want ```MyVec <- 1:10```? Or at the bottom of the loop ```myVec[a] <- a```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to fill `myVec` in this way

```
a <- 0
b <- 10
myVec <- c()
while (a < b) {
  a <- a+1
  myVec <- c(myVec,a)
  print(a)
}
```

such that

```
> myVec
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```